# Restful range queries for multiple ids

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I'm looking at designing an API that not only supports access to a single resource, but also access to multiple resources at once.

For example, each user has 20 friends.

```
GET foobar.com/users/me/friends/1
```

Would return friend number 1. Getting all users is also no problem, but in case I want to get multiple specific users could I use a queries like the following one?

```
GET foobar.com/users/me/friends?id=1,3,5-9,20
```

Or is there a better way to achieve that?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache-friendly way to do what you're looking for is to issue a series of `GET` requests, one for each user. The problem with your approach is that these two requests are cached separately, despite the fact that most of the data returned is identical:

```
GET foobar.com/users/me/friends?id=1-10
GET foobar.com/users/me/friends?id=1-9
```

If /friends is returning a collection of results with very limited data and hyperlinks to get at the full data for a friend, then your approach is reasonable. If friend data cannot be cached on the client and you don't support conditional `GET`s it should also be OK - but then if you add those features later you won't be leveraging them here. If the collection is returning the full data set for each friend, consider taking advantage of caching/conditional `GET`s and issuing separate requests for each user.

And don't say "performance" until you've tested in a real-world environment and there's a proven issue! :-)

Comment: Performance can also be better with a series of GET requests because the server's response time for an aggregated query is NEVER faster than the lookup of the friend that takes LONGEST to return. Plus, you cannot indicate "some items not found" as a response code, which usually leads to dirty workarounds like usage of WebDAV's HTTP 207.